# Changing Resolution in OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, fullscreen, resolution, opentk

I've been searching around for this, I've managed to find out out to change the size of our window, and how to change the resolution of the monitor.

But I can't seem to find how to tell OpenGL where and how big my viewport is.

Example: the game starts up in 400x300, and I expand the window to 800x600. I now have a 800x600 window, but only a 400x300 box in the corner is being rendered to.
I get the same problem when switching to fullscreen, the gray area covers the entire screen, but I only have a small box in the corner being rendered to.

Any OpenTK people out there that know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh your viewport:

```
GL.Viewport(gameWindow.ClientRectangle);
```